# Kotlin: MyClass::class.java vs this.javaClass

Tags: java, classloader, kotlin

I'm migrating a project to Kotlin, and this:

```
public static Properties provideProperties(String propertiesFileName) {
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    InputStream inputStream = null;
    try {
        inputStream = ObjectFactory.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(propertiesFileName);
        properties.load(inputStream);
        return properties;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (inputStream != null) {
            try {
                inputStream.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

is now:

```
fun provideProperties(propertiesFileName: String): Properties? {
    return Properties().apply {
        ObjectFactory::class.java.classLoader.getResourceAsStream(propertiesFileName).use { stream ->
            load(stream)
        }
    }
}
```

very nice, Kotlin! :P

The question is: this method looks for a `.properties` file inside `src/main/resources`. Using:

```
ObjectFactory::class.java.classLoader...
```

it works, but using:

```
this.javaClass.classLoader...
```

`classLoader` is `null`...

[image]

[image]

[image]

(note that the memory address is also different)

Why?

Thanks

Comment: Are you getting the error at runtime or compile-time?

Comment: at runtime, I debugged and `javaClass` is not null, but `javaClass.classLoader` is

Comment: Oh, Kotlin. What if you explicitly use `getClassLoader()`? Shouldn't be different, but I don't know what sort of access bytecode the Kotlin compiler is emitting. If `getClassLoader()` is non-null, looks like a compiler bug. If it *is* null, post the value of `javaClass`.

Comment: `javaClass` is null.. I added two screenshots.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you invoke `javaClass` inside a lambda passed to [`apply`](http://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/apply.html), it's called on the *implicit receiver* of that lambda. Since `apply` turns its own receiver (`Properties()` in this case) into the implicit receiver of the lambda, you're effectively getting the Java class of the `Properties` object you've created. This is of course different from the Java class of `ObjectFactory` you're getting with `ObjectFactory::class.java`.

For a very thorough explanation of how implicit receivers work in Kotlin, you can read [this spec document](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/master/spec-docs/NameResolution.adoc#implicit-and-explicit-receivers).

Comment: Brief yet demonstrative explanation of explicit receivers: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/this-expressions.html